# ReactJS Download PDF library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my supervisor wants to implement a premium react download PDF in our web application do you have a suggestion on what react library/plugin/third-party tools to use for Downloading a PDF? It should be paid reactjs Download PDF

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This one works perfectly fine on both frontend and back end http://pdfmake.org/#/